# How to show the custom admin module(. phtml view) under the Magento Menu ribbon

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to Magento, developed my first custom admin module "HelloWorld"
It's working fine but the `.phtml` page opens in another tab, I want it to open in the same place where other Magento tabs gets open (i.e. under the same ribbon)

Below are the code from the files

`config.xml` File

````
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_HelloWorld>
     <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Company_HelloWorld>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <helloworld>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Company_HelloWorld</module>
          <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
        </args>
      </helloworld>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
<admin>
  <routers>
    <helloworld>
     <use>admin</use>
     <args>
      <module before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_HelloWorld</module>
      <frontName>admin_helloworld</frontName>
     </args>
    </helloworld>
  </routers>
</admin>
<global>
  <helpers>
    <helloworld>
      <class>Company_HelloWorld_Helper</class>
    </helloworld>
  </helpers>
  <blocks>
            <helloworld>
                <class>Company_Helloworld_Block</class>
            </helloworld>
        </blocks>
</global>
<adminhtml>
 <menu>
   <helloworld module="helloworld">
     <title>HelloWorld</title>
     <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    <children>
      <helloworld module="helloworld">
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
        <action>admin_helloworld/adminhtml_index</action>
      </helloworld>
    </children>
   </helloworld>
 </menu>
  <layout>
    <updates>
    <HelloWorld>
        <file>Company_HelloWorld.xml</file> 
    </HelloWorld>
    </updates>
</layout>
</adminhtml>
</config>```  

```Company_HelloWorld.xml```
```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <HelloWorld_adminhtml_index_index>
         <reference name="head">
                <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                    <title>Module</title>
                </action>
            </reference>
         <modules>
           <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" name="Company_HelloWorld" template="HelloWorld/simple_page.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </modules>
     </HelloWorld_adminhtml_index_index>
</layout>
````

Comment: put code so we able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Hey found the solution!

Instead of trying to apply Magento Theme to my page, I have now put the contents of my page there, just like:

```
$this->loadLayout();

$this->_setActiveMenu('helloworld');

$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('helloworld/adminhtml_adminblock'));

$this->renderLayout()
```

Now I am able to open my page same as other Magento tabs do!